# Reuse ldap connection in WildFly

Tags: ldap, wildfly

In `standalone.xml` I have `security-realm` defined for LDAP authentication and authorization. This security realm uses a connection defined in `outbound-connections`.

I also use naming subsystem to define `external-context`, which I use in Java class for making some changes in LDAP.

**The question is:** Can I somehow reuse the outbound connection when defining external context? I don't want to give LDAP configuration properties again. Or maybe there is some other solution for this - to have LDAP connection defined in one place in `standalone.xml` and reuse it for security realm and naming subsystem?

**One extra question:** If I want to move from JNDI to LDAP library (like UnboundID), can I still reuse this connection from `standalone.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the outbound connections defined in the management section of the configuration are exclusively for use by LDAP backed security realms.  The reason I split them out was so that multiple realm definitions could share the same connections but they are not usable elsewhere in the server.